# Awesome debounce promise dosn't work with calling function?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, debouncing

I am using awesome-debounce-promise with simple react application to delay function execution, which firing a action to update header in database. I am using redux-saga and axios too, and official examples which uses const, doesn't work, because I create api call in axios...onChange action I call this function...

```
    changeCity = (e) => {
    let storedHeader = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('offer_header'))
      if(storedHeader !== null) {
        let updatedHeader = {
            id : storedHeader.id,
            customer : storedHeader === null ? this.state.customer : storedHeader.customer,
            address : storedHeader === null ? this.state.address : storedHeader.address,
            city : e.target.value,
            date : storedHeader === null ? moment(this.state.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00") : moment(storedHeader.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00"),
            price : parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('offer_header_price')),
            tax : parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('offer_header_price')) * 0.21,
            total : parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('offer_header_price')),
        }
        const result = AwesomeDebouncePromise(this.props.editHeaderDB(updatedHeader), 2000);
        console.log('result = ', result);
    }
    this.setState({
        city: e.target.value
    })
}
```

snippet code of api.js

```
export function editOfferHeader_api(header) {
   return axios.put(apiUrl + '/offerHeader/' + header.id ,header)
}
```

and saga.js is

```
export function* editOfferHeaderDB(action) {
const response = yield call(editOfferHeader_api, action.payload)
if(!response && (!response.data || !response.message)) {
    return yield put(editOfferHeaderDB_failure('Internal server error editing offer header'))
}
if(response.status === 200) {
    localStorage.setItem('offer_header', JSON.stringify(response.data))
    return yield put(editOfferHeaderDB_success(response.data))
} else {
    return yield put(editOfferHeaderDB_failure('Error editing offer header'))
}
```

}

Can someone help me, how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that you use the **same** debounced function, and not recall `AwesomeDebouncePromise` every time.

Because each calls will create a new function and so it will defeat the purpose of debouncing.

So you must first create your debounced function, preferably at the top level, and the reuse it through out your code.

(edit: example)

```js
export const editOfferHeader_api = AwesomeDebouncePromise(
  function (header) {
    return axios.put(apiUrl + '/offerHeader/' + header.id ,header)
  },
  2000,
)
```

Comment: can you write me simple example?

Comment: @Qli Added an example on how I would just wrap the API call in the debounce and export that instead.

You would then in the rest of your code not need to use `AwesomeDebouncePromise` anymore for this function.